# event when closing a Window, but without closing it

Tags: java, events, user-interface

I want to show a "Confirm Close" window when closing the main app window, but without making it disappear. Right now I am using a `windowsListener`, and more specifially the `windowsClosing` event, but when using this event the main window is closed and I want to keep it opened.

Here is the code I am using:

To register the listener

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                thisWindowClosing(evt);
            }
        });
```

The implementation of the handling event:

```
private void thisWindowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
    new closeWindow(this);
}
```

Also I've tried using `this.setVisible(true)` in the `thisWindowClosing()` method but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: +1 for a common scenario I never thought about the implementation of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package org.apache.people.mclark.examples;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClosingFrame extends JFrame {

    public ClosingFrame() {
        final JFrame frame = this;
        // Setting DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE is important, don't forget!
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                        "Really Exit?", "Confirm Exit",
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    frame.dispose(); // close the window
                } else {
                    // else let the window stay open
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ClosingFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't work. The main window is closed once you click on Cancel.

Comment: I don't know what to say. It works perfectly for me under Java 5 and Java 6. Make sure you paste and compile my example program exactly as it is, to prove that my code is working. Only then should you begin moving my approach over to your existing code. Did you remember to call frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); on your frame?

Comment: Exactly...that was the problem. If I call "this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE" to my code. It works perfectly. That you so mach!